# What event is called when we click on a DataGridViewComboBoxCell

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I have a list of item in a DataGridViewComboBoxCell; I want to do something as soon as the user click on a value.

What is the event, or how could I do what I want?

CellValueChanged is called when we leave the cell...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle the selectededindexchanged of the combobox.

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, 
                    DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cb = e.Control as ComboBox;
    if (cb != null)
    {
        // first remove event handler to keep from attaching multiple:
        cb.SelectedIndexChanged -= new
        EventHandler(cb_SelectedIndexChanged);

        // now attach the event handler
        cb.SelectedIndexChanged += new 
        EventHandler(cb_SelectedIndexChanged);
    }
}

void cb_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Selected index changed");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I use your base idea and I was able to finish my work!!!
A lots of pressure is now away...

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way of doing it is:

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender,  
                                                 DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cb = e.Control as ComboBox;
    if (cb == null)
        return;

    dataGridView1.EditingControlShowing -= dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing;
    cb.SelectedIndexChanged += cb_SelectedIndexChanged;
}

void cb_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Selected index changed");
}
```

You are doing everything just once.